# how can we get images through cache once they are in memory and how to make such a logic

Tags: java

I am making a web application, I want to store images in cache. Next time I don't want to get images from network. How can I implement using java, using `WeakHashmap` or `Hashmap`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have class `NetworkImageService` which fetches image remotely:

```
class NetworkImageService {

    public Image getImage(name) { ... }

}
```

Then you can subclass it to have `CachedNetworkImageService`, like this:

```
 class CachedNetworkImageService extends NetworkImageService {

    Cache cache = new Cache();

    public Image getImage(name) { ... 
          Image img = cache.get(name);
          if( img == null ) {
                 img = super.getImage(name);
                 cache.put( name, img );
          }
          return img.
    }
}
```

That's the basic idea of how I do usually (but it's pseudo-code). You can of course improve it and use for instance `cache.contains()` instead to check against `null`.

In the most basic case, you can substitute `Cache` with `Hashmap`. Otherwise you can improve this and implement various strategies in the cache. You can have an eviction policy that remove image after some time, or following a LIFO scheme.

The code above does not support concurrent access, so you would also need to consider that. The most basic way to make it thread-safe is to synchronize the method `getImage()`.